# Detect if a physical keyboard is connected in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, accessibility

Is there a way to detect if there is a PHYSICAL keyboard connected in Flutter?  I would like to detect if the user is using a physical keyboard, and alter the UI depending on if this is so.

Answer (score 2):

Has this changed? I would also like to detect if a keyboard is connected/available. I'm currently reacting when a physical keyboard is used with a RawKeyboardListener but it would be a smoother experience for the end user if I could see if a keyboard was connected, before it's actually used.

Looks like this is available in Android native: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard

Not sure if it's available on iOS but we have the RawKeyboardListener approach that is OK on iOS. For Android we are supporting Chromebooks with physical keyboards and to provide the best experience we would like to react as early as possible to physical keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the physical keyboard has been used (but not when it connects), you could listen to keyboard events by listening to `RawKeyboard.instance.addListener`, and switch modes if you see a key event: `RawKeyboard` only sends physical keyboard events.

But to answer your question, no, there's no specific notification for when a physical keyboard is connected.

Comment: The `TextField` widget in the current version of Flutter (3.10.5) sadly prevents listeners from being triggered for printable characters. (But e.g. backspace still works.)